# How do I mock constructor state initialisation with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

New to node.js.  I am writing a JS API client that wraps the underlying [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library. In the unit tests I am mocking axios using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/en/).

In the constructor of my API class I pass in a URL, and use the [`axios.create`](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) function to create a custom instance of axios and bind it to the the client property.

The problem arises when I mock the axios dependency with `jest.mock('axios')` - A TypeError is being thrown in the test when an attempt is made to call `axios.get`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property `get` of undefined
```

I understand why this is happening, but I've not found a way to enable me to mock axios and not have the client field be undefined.  Is there a way to get around this, other than injecting axios through the constructor?

Client code and test below:

---

**client.js**

```
jest.mock("axios");
const axios = require("axios");
const mockdata = require("./mockdata");
const ApiClient = require("../../../src/clients/apiclient");


const BASE_URL = "https://www.mock.url.com"

const mockAxiosGetWith = mockResponse => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(mockResponse);
};

test("should make one get request",  async () => {
  mockAxiosGetWith(MOCK_RESPONSE)

  // the client field in apiclient is undefined
  // due to the jest module mocking of axios
  const apiclient = new ApiClient.AsyncClient(BASE_URL);


  // TypeError: Cannot read property `get` of undefined
  return await apiclient.get("something").then(response => {
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

});
```

---

**client.test.js**

```
const axios = require("axios");

const getClient = (baseUrl = null) => {
  const options = {
    baseURL: baseUrl
  };

  const client = axios.create(options);

  return client;
};

module.exports = {
  AsyncClient: class ApiClient {
    constructor(baseUrl = null) {
      this.client = getClient(baseUrl);
    }

    get(url, conf = {}) {
      return this.client
        .get(url, conf)
        .then(response => Promise.resolve(response))
        .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
    }

  }
};
```

Comment: You don't  mock axios implementation. There should be `jest.mock("axios", () => ({ get: jest.fn }))`. I can't say if it's the only problem here.

Comment: @estuthanks for replying.  jest allows module mocking which automatically mocks each exported function with a jest.fn - this is not the issue here.

Comment: But `axios` only export an object holding the `create` function. Which is not the same as having a module that export `create` directly. So @estusis right with his suggestion on how to mock `axios`. Even the real mocking should look differently. I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to mock `axios` so it will return an object which holds the `create` function which should return the object with the `get`

```
import axios from 'axios'
jest.mock('axios', () => ({create: jest.fn()}))


test("should make one get request",  async () => {
  const get = jest.fn(()=>Promise.resolve(MOCK_RESPONSE))
  axios.create.mockImplementation(()=>({get}))

  const apiclient = new ApiClient.AsyncClient(BASE_URL);

  await apiclient.get("something")
  expect(get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

});
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas Koberle - this works,  and now I understand Jest mocking better thanks to you and @estus.  Have upvoted both you and estus's  comment ,and flagged this  answer as correct. Cheers!